# Is it possible to enable two keyspace in Cassandra to be replicated?

Tags: database, cassandra, replication, distributed, sdn

I have two networks where each network is controlled using a separate SDNcontroller. Each network stores its data in its own store. I want to enable these two controllers to communicate with each other to exchange data between them.
I will build these data stores using Cassandra, but my question in this case: Do I need to build each store in a separate keyspace or I can create both stores in a single keyspace?

in case of two keysapces, Is it possible to enable replication( consistancy) between them in cassandra?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Replication in Cassandra pertains to keeping certain number of copies (equal to replication factor)  of one particular keyspace. If both the the networks can be represented by same data model then you should keep single keyspace. You can add data of both the network in same keyspace.

Comment: so, is it applicable to store the data of both networks in a single keyspace and allow replication between stores so each network can have a copy of other network data